# Authenticate to Facebook without Clicking Facebook Connect Button

Tags: facebook

I have added Facebook Connect to my application via the JavaScript SDK.  I'm using Spring Security (this is a grails app) and I have added code that when someone clicks the FB Connection button to login, I manually authenticate them against their user account and everything gets wired up appropriately.  I have 2 questions:

1. When a user first logs in with FB and I don't have an account for them, I create an account for them with their FB info, generate a random password, and use their email for their login name.  If the user then uses the regular login form instead of the FB button to sign in, how do I sign them in to FB as well?
2. Every time the user clicks the FB Connect button, the popup window shows up.  If they are already authenticated, it just goes away and then my web site redirects correctly.  How do I keep the popup window from showing up in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To you first question, the user might be connect on Facebook when landing on your page after registration. So you can rely on the Javascript SDK to help you out.

See here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus

To your second question, I think you can't, except you might get a work around if you use the Javascript SDK mentioned for the first question!

This is how I did it for moviezine.se and it works just fine, but it might be a little irritating to be logged in without asking for it when you come back a few days later. Then there is the use case of the logout: if you are automatically logged in, are you automatically logged out too; and if not, what if your Facebook session is replaced by your girlfriend's one who is also a user on your site! :)

Comment: Thanks Nicolas.  Other sites are working without the extra window every time.  And users can login via FB or their site creds.  And both accounts get logged in.  The problem is that the facebook connect button doesn't have a beforeSubmit callback of any kind.  Sure, I can use the getLoginStatus to show/hide the button.  But that only gets me so far.  My system requires it's own authentication.  Right now, when they authenticate through FB, I manually auth them to my system.  I'm storing the user's FB ID in my database to help with this.

Comment: I need to be able to go the other way as well.  When a user logs in via my login form, and there is a FB account associated with them, it auths to both.

Comment: How about using a custom button calling FB.login() when necessary? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login

Comment: Also, if the user is logged in on Facebook, you can assume it on your side, but nothing can replace the Facebook authentication, so even if you identity the user with a custom login/pass, you will need to prompt the user to login on Facebook if you need it. When having multiple authentication methods (Twitter + Facebook + ...), I recommend you rely on a different Session cookie than the different ones. Then you can have user identified but authenticated on only one or several services...